# PHP MySQL price range not working

Tags: php, mysql

i'm trying to use price range with a SELECT dropdown like this:

```
<select name="valor">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Faixa de Valor</option>
    <option value="100000.00 , 200000.00">De R$ 100 a 200 mil</option>
    <option value="200000.00 , 500000.00">De R$  200 a 500 mil</option>
    <option value="500000.00 , 1000000.00">De R$  500 a 1 milhão</option>
    <option value="1000000.00 , 5000000.00">De R$ 1 a 5 milhões</option>
    <option value="5000000.00">Acima de 5 Milhões</option>
</select>
```

and my PHP statement is:

```
$valor_query = $_POST['valor'];
$values = explode(' , ', $valor_query);
$valor1 = $values[0];
$valor2 = $values[1];
$statements .= " AND ( (property_selling.valor >= '$valor1' AND property_selling.valor >= '$valor2') OR (property_renting.valor >= '$valor1' AND property_renting.valor >= '$valor2') ) ";
```

But it's not working, i have 2 different tables, one for selling and another for renting and i'm adding this statement as a variable like this:

```
$filtraSegmento = "SELECT * FROM properties, property_complements,
property_details, property_selling, property_renting 
WHERE property_complements.imovel_id = properties.property_id 
AND property_details.imovel_id = properties.property_id 
AND (property_renting.imovel_id = properties.property_id 
OR property_selling.imovel_id = properties.property_id) 
AND properties.property_status = 'Aprovado' $statements 
GROUP BY properties.property_id";
```

Any hints?

**EDIT**

As suggested by @Strawberry and @Sean, i have recreated the query using LEFT JOIN, now it looks like:

```
$filtraSegmento = "
SELECT p.*, c.*, d.*, s.*, r.* 
   FROM properties p
   LEFT 
   JOIN property_complements c
     ON c.imovel_id = p.property_id
   LEFT 
   JOIN property_details d 
     ON d.imovel_id = p.property_id
   LEFT 
   JOIN property_selling s 
     ON s.imovel_id = p.property_id
   LEFT 
   JOIN property_renting r 
     ON r.imovel_id = p.property_id
  WHERE $statements
";
```

It works nicely now, but my problem is, i'm using this as a filter, while user keep filtering, the variable `$statements`keep adding new conditions. So i have this in an array format like:

```
$statements = '';
if (isset($_POST['segmento']) && !empty($_POST['segmento'])) {
   $segmento_query = $_POST['segmento'];
    $statements .= " detail.segmento = '$segmento_query' "; //condition for each property
}
if (isset($_POST['cidade']) && !empty($_POST['cidade'])) {
   $cidade_query = $_POST['cidade'];
   $statements .= " detail.cidade = '$cidade_query '";
}
if (isset($_POST['tipo_imovel']) && !empty($_POST['tipo_imovel'])) {
   $tipo_query = $_POST['tipo_imovel'];
   $statements .= " detail.tipo_imovel = '$tipo_query '";
}
if (isset($_POST['local']) && !empty($_POST['local'])) {
   $local_query = $_POST['local'];
   $statements .= " property.property_category = '$local_query '";
}
if (isset($_POST['valor']) && !empty($_POST['valor'])) {
   $valor_query = $_POST['valor'];
       $values = explode(',', $valor_query);
       $valor1 = $values[0];
       $valor2 = $values[1];
       $statements .= " selling.valor BETWEEN '$valor1' AND '$valor2' OR renting.valor BETWEEN '$valor1' AND '$valor2' ";
}
```

How can i make it add to the query as a new condition?

Comment: what is `$valor_query` ?

Comment: Are you trying to join the tables ?

Comment: `valor` is a string or `int/float`?

Comment: Yes, i'm not sure if i did it correctly (In other pages are working correctly) just this page that i need to query a price range its not working

Comment: @chris85, valor is a DECIMAL (19,2) from database

Comment: Can you echo the $filtraSegmento ?

Comment: You have `>=` on both -> `...(property_selling.valor >= '$valor1' AND property_selling.valor >= '$valor2')...`. Shouldn't it be `>=`/`<=` -> `...(property_selling.valor >= '$valor1' AND property_selling.valor <= '$valor2')...`

Comment: @Sean, i've changed that but still not working.

Comment: @zeflex, `SELECT * FROM properties, property_complements, property_details, property_selling, property_renting WHERE property_complements.imovel_id = properties.property_id AND property_details.imovel_id = properties.property_id AND (property_renting.imovel_id = properties.property_id OR property_selling.imovel_id = properties.property_id) AND properties.property_status = 'Aprovado'  AND ( (property_selling.valor <= '1000000.00' AND property_selling.valor >= '5000000.00') OR (property_renting.valor <= '1000000.00' AND property_renting.valor >= '5000000.00') )  GROUP BY properties.property_id`

Comment: May be the problem is that you compare decimal with string? You need to cast string to decimal

Comment: @user1551066, how can i do that?

Comment: Your query on comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32132051/php-mysql-price-range-not-working#comment52155003_32132051 does not make sense. How can `property_selling.valor <= '1000000.00' AND property_selling.valor >= '5000000.00'` ever be true? You want a number that is smaller than `1000000.00`, but larger than `5000000.00`. That can't be possible. Same with `property_renting.valor <= '1000000.00' AND property_renting.valor >= '5000000.00'`. You have your `<=` and `>=` backwards.

Comment: @Sean, you're right, i changed that because i didnt knew what to do anymore, my last query was:  `AND ( (property_selling.valor BETWEEN '$valor1' AND '$valor2') OR (property_renting.valor BETWEEN '$valor1' AND '$valor2') )`

Comment: @Sean, But that does not work as well :(

Comment: Like this "CAST(' $values[0]' AS DECIMAL(10,2))"

Comment: One big question guys, should i use OR condition between selling and renting tables if i'm going to retrieve records from both?

Comment: Yes, if you want data returned from both tables you will need an `OR`. If you used an `AND` you would only return rows if it was in **both** the selling and renting tables.

Comment: @Sean, Sure, do this is not the problem,i can't really understand why is not working, i'll try to remove all the queries and see if `valor` works alone.

Comment: Well, it didn't worked :(

Comment: So is your query with `valor` returning `0` rows? Or are you getting an error message? Can you provide some sample data from your tables. Maybe create a simple http://sqlfiddle.com/ that can be used?

Comment: @Sean, the `$valor_query = $_POST['valor'];` are the values coming from the dropdown, then i explode them because i'm sending 2 values, and i get `$valor1` and `$valor2` as the values, in my database the column `valor` is DECIMAL(10,2)

Comment: I know about that. My question was does your query without `$statements` (ie. your `.valor =` conditions) return rows, but with the `$statements` (ie. your `.valor =` conditions) it returns `0` rows? Do you have rows that are within those ranges?

Comment: @Sean, i'll try to use sqlfiddle.com, mayeb could be better to debug, hold on please.

Comment: Here is it @Sean, [db_test](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1dbd7/1)

Comment: It returns the rows, but wron, like it was ignoring the statement

Comment: In your sqlfiddle, you have your `GROUP BY properties.property_id` before your `AND ( (property_selling.valor BETWEEN '1000000.00' AND '5000000.00') OR (property_renting.valor BETWEEN '1000000.00' AND '5000000.00') )` so it is now a part of the `GROUP BY`, and not part of the `WHERE`. Try moving it before the `GROUP BY` and see if that works.

Comment: Ok, here is the result: [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1dbd7/3) now i get the desired result, but it's returning also the renting property that does not match the `valor`

Comment: My guess is your issue is you are loosely joining your tables - `SELECT * FROM properties, property_details, property_selling, property_renting` - where you are joining **each** row with `property_selling` **and** `property_renting`. You might need to do a `UNION` query with 2 queries, but you will have issues as `property_selling` and `property_renting` have different amount of columns.

Comment: A GROUP BY clause has no business being in this query. Can you rewrite your query using proper join syntax and formatting. Proper formatting might look like this... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1dbd7/3 ...I'll leave you to figure out the joins

Comment: i'll try that today, i'll come back tomorrow with results if i got it working or not. Thanks for the help so far, and thanks @Sean, i'll see what i can do here.

Comment: @Strawberry, alright, i'll try that and come back with the results, thanks for the help so far.

Comment: @Strawberry just to understand, i need to use proper formatting using JOINS and at the end i use the WHERE statementes?

Comment: Approvado and price range may or may not appear in a WHERE clause depending on the type of JOIN required.

Comment: Ok, so i have made another test where i removed all related to `property_renting` from the query, and it worked just fine for `property_selling` values, probably the way i'm using `OR` condition could be wrong?

Comment: @Strawberry, i got it working, but now it's another problem, i'll update my question and you'll see.

Comment: @Strawberry, updated the question, i need the variable `$statement` to keep adding `AND` conditions, how can that be done with the new query?

Comment: Any conditions attached to a LEFT JOINed table would need to appear in that JOIN's 'ON' clause.

Comment: @Strawberry, but then i use `WHERE` on each `LEFT JOIN` as conditions?

Comment: No. That would defeat the point of using an OUTER JOIN. So "...FROM x LEFT JOIN y ON y.id = x.id AND y.fruit = 'apple'..."

Comment: This way then? `LEFT JOIN property_details AS detail ON property.property_id = detail.imovel_id AND detail.segmento = '$segmento_query'`

Comment: @Strawberry, i tried this but i get all results instead of filtering `LEFT JOIN property_details AS detail ON property.property_id = detail.imovel_id AND detail.segmento = '$segmento_query'`

Comment: About 3 hours ago, someone should have suggested that you provide proper CREATE and INSERTs and a desired result, based upon a typical set of conditions. I would suggest you delete this question, and start over with something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like nested conditional operator instead of exploding submitted values. Use values like 1,2,3,..for options and in you php do can do like this.

```
$r = $_POST["valor"]
 ".(
    empty($r) ? "" : ( ($r == "0") ? "" :
        ( ($r == "1") ? "and rent <= 5000" :
             ( ($r == "2") ? "and rent between 5000 and 10000" : "and rent > 10000" )                  
             )
        )
)."
```